# Do all decomposition reactions involve heat?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry

When water decomposes into Hydrogen and Oxygen as in 2H2O—-> 2H2+O2 does this involve heat? Is it always implied that heat is involved in a decomposition reaction or does this just spontaneously occur? Chemistry 1st semester so excuse the fundamental nature of the question. Thanks

Comment: Water: yes. Always: no.

Answer (score 2):

Plainly put: no, decomposition reaction does not always have to entail providing heat. A decomposition reaction (in simple language) is when one compound breaks into multiple other compounds, like so:

$$\ce{A -> B + C}$$

As a general rule, if the product side is relatively more stable, it will decompose without you having the to provide extra heat. In the case of the reaction you gave, $\ce{H2O}$ is more stable than $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{O2}$, and thus you will have to provide heat for the breaking of bonds.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [iron oxygen phase diagram](https://www.google.com/search?q=iron+oxygen+phase+diagram&oq=oron+oxygen+phase+diagram&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.12123j0j7&client=ms-android-verizon&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#imgrc=VVWg_gy5oPVY5M:).  Wustite ($\ce{FeO}$) decomposes upon ... cooling, below 570°C, to magnetite ($\ce{Fe_3O_4}$) and metallic iron.  Steel strip manufacturers deal with this reaction because it impacts the acid pickling of hot mill scale.